# Showing that $f$ grows fastest along path for which $\gamma'(t)=\nabla f(\gamma(t))$ than along any other path?

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Show that $f$ grows fastest along path for which $\gamma'(t)=\nabla
>  f(\gamma(t))$ than along any other path.

My reasoning is that of course $f$ along $\gamma$ must be growing the fastest since by definition the gradient at a point $x_0$ is the direction to which the function grows fastest and its magnitude gives the steepness of the growth.

But what about "any other path"?

Comment: Related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401845/why-the-nabla-fx-in-the-direction-orthogonal-to-fx/402080#402080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\eta$ be any other path. Then the growth of $f$ along $\eta$ is measured by the the derivative: $(f\circ \eta)'(t)=\nabla f(\eta(t))\cdot\eta'(t)$, which by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is $\leq || \nabla f(\eta(t)||\ || \eta'(t)||$. Therefore, the maximum value of the derivative will be attained when this is an equality, i.e. when the vectors are parallel. In other words, when $\eta'(t)=\lambda \nabla f(\eta(t))$, for some $\lambda$.

However, note that you can always reparametrize $\eta$ to get $\lambda=1$.

Comment: So how does this relate to $f(\gamma (t))$?

Comment: $f(\gamma(t))$ precisely satisfies that $(f\circ\gamma)'(t) = || \nabla f(\gamma(t)) ||^2$, or in other words, it makes the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, an equality, therefore attaining the maximum value.

Comment: Why does it satisfy that?

Comment: Because of your hypothesis that $\gamma'(t)=\nabla f(\gamma(t))$. Just substitute in the inequality in my answer. Note that $\eta$ is any path, in particular you can choose $\gamma$

Comment: Do you know if using C-S is the only way to solve this?

Comment: I don't know of any other proof unfortunately